# Difference between AWS Software Subscription and Launching a Custom AMI?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-12.04, amazon-ami

Amazon AWS seems to provide two methods of launching an instance of Ubuntu 12.04 that confuse me,

- one of them is the [Software Marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/ordering/ref=dtl_psb_continue?ie=UTF8&productId=5cc062dc-4b61-4424-bc43-416e51483a1f&region=us-east-1)
- the other method is by launching an [AMI on the Ubuntu website](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/)

**All of these comparisons are 12.04 LTS, Micro, w/ amd64 architecture**

With the [Software Marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/ordering/ref=dtl_psb_continue?ie=UTF8&productId=5cc062dc-4b61-4424-bc43-416e51483a1f&region=us-east-1), I see these AMI ids for a Micro Instance:

```
AMI IDs
Region                            ID
US East (Virginia)                ami-967edcff
US West (Oregon)                  ami-c6cc43f6
US West (Northern California)     ami-997356dc
EU West (Ireland)                 ami-e7b6b393
Asia Pacific (Singapore)          ami-5e01400c
Asia Pacific (Tokyo)              ami-c83c8fc9
South America (Sao Paulo)         ami-ea3ce2f7
```

However, with the [Ubuntu Website](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/) I see,

```
Zone            AMI-ID          AKI-ID
us-east-1       ami-83dee0ea    aki-88aa75e1
eu-west-1       ami-aa56a1dd    aki-71665e05
ap-southeast-1  ami-bc7325ee    aki-fe1354ac
us-west-1       ami-c45f6281    aki-f77e26b2
us-west-2       ami-d0d8b8e0    aki-fc37bacc
sa-east-1       ami-d55bfbc8    aki-c48f51d9
ap-southeast-2  ami-e577e9df    aki-31990e0b
ap-northeast-1  ami-f72e45f6    aki-44992845
```

What is the difference say between `ami-83dee0ea` (from Ubuntu Website), and `ami-967edcff` (from the AWS Software Marketplace).

Answer (score 0):

I can't point on the exact difference but the AMIs have different owners (or maintainer).
So it is possible that there are not all packages up-to-date on any image...

I assume the AMIs on the ubuntu page are maintained directly by Canonical and the others possibly by Amazon.

Most of the time you can choose whatever way you want. I prefer using the EC2 web console and so using the AMIs which are in the marketplace.

Hope that helps.